# Django in Eclipse, laying out the project

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

Any "best practice" or "recommended" project layouts for a django project in eclipse?

In my eclipse it looks like this:

```
project name
-src
--project name
---__init__.py
---manage.py
---settings.py
---urls.py
---apps
----app1
-----__init__.py
-----forms.py
-----urls.py
-----views.py
-----templates
------app1
-------index.html
```

I'm not sure how I like this layout, especially the repetition of the app name in the templates folder.  I think I did it that way to make my url configs behave, but I'm new to django so that could be another place for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you know you can create a django project without the src folder in eclipse which i think will be much cleaner; to do this when you want to create a new Django project the widget that ask for the name of the project in the bottom you can disable **Create default "scr" ...** .

And i don't think it's a good idea to put all Django application like you did you can put related application in the some folder but not all of them , and for the template i think you have the choice to put one template directory in the some level as settings.py where you can have the same structure as your apps or to put a template directory in each application but i prefer the first one like this:

```
project_name
  |
  | --- manage.py
  |
  | --- settings.py
  |
  | --- template
          |
          | -- index.html
          |
          | -- base.html
          |
          | -- 404.html
          | 
          | -- conection_app
          |         | 
                    | -- login.html
  |
  |
  | --- connection_app
          |
          | -- login
                 |
                 | -- view.py
  |
  |
  | --- finance_app 
  |
```

Comment: i like this way of laying out a project

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to have one app, you don't need an apps folder. Also, it should just be `templates/index.html`, since templates lives in app1's folder. There's no chance that you'd have another app's templates in app1's folder.

I also don't really see why you need to have a project-name folder underneath `src`... Is that some sort of Django hack, because if it isn't I can't imagine why it would be necessary.

Comment: I had more than one app, I just didn't want to list them all

Comment: Okay, keep the apps folder, but you don't need `template/app1`

Answer (score 1):

For Django, you'll absolutely want to duplicate the app name in the template folder.

If you have "app1" and "app2", and they both have an "index.html" template, then you need the app name in the path to differentiate the templates.

Say you want to pack-in default templates for "app1" but let users override them, then you can have "app1/templates/app1/index.html", and the override can go in "templates/app1/index.html" or wherever.

Without the app name in the folder, you're setting yourself up for template name collisions.